# Syntax Error in Controller#Index in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

Im going to build an Ruby on Rails based Application with a little data base. But when I created the db with the scaffold tool I got an Syntax Error when I try to call the page via `localhost:3000/informations`.

On the top of the page:

```
SyntaxError in InformationsController#index

c:/anwendung/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:24: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end 
c:/anwendung/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:26: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

this is the code of `application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Anwendung</title>
  <% if mobile_device? %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'sencha-touch' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'touch/sencha-touch' %>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
  <% else %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>
</end>
</body>
</html>
```

It would be really nice if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing `<% end %>` for your `if-else` condition. Also, HTML tags are not well paired.

Try this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Anwendung</title>
  <% if mobile_device? %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'sencha-touch' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'touch/sencha-touch' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <% end %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but after I fixed your refernces the next Error occured. This time something is wrong with the mobile device detection. I guess I have to fix some more points... 'undefined method `mobile_device?' for #<#<Class:0x47fde70>:0x3935658>'

Comment: Obviously you need to have `mobile_device?` helper method defined and accessible. You should define it in `ApplicationHelper`. Anyways, you should add another question for it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242482/syntax-error-in-controllerindex-in-ruby-on-rails#comment39325510_25242588